# Wso2 is clustering Not able to login on management console of wso2 identity server

Tags: nginx, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have configured 2 wso2 IS server instances in the local windows environment according to the documentation provided https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0%2C+5.2.0+and+5.3.0
and also the NGINX configuration with self signed certificates

I have been redirecting to the wso2 is login page of any one node but when logging in its redirecting to the login page again but at log showing

**[2017-05-24 15:52:26,528]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2017-05-24 15:52:26,528+0530]**

Its working properly with one node(other is down).

I am not able to figure out where is the issue, both nodes are working properly no error in the logs,

Please help ,

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable [sticky sessions](https://www.nginx.com/products/session-persistence/) in nginx configurations. See [WSO2 doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+NGINX) too.

Comment: Thanks , I did the configuration but its still the same,apache configuration :ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
 ProxyPass / balancer://wso2.is.com/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=On
 ProxyPassReverse / https://wso2.is.com:9444/
 ProxyPassReverse / https://wso2.is.com:9445/
<Proxy balancer://wso2.is.com>
 BalancerMember https://wso2.is.com:9444 route=isNode2 loadfactor=1
 BalancerMember https://wso2.is.com:9445 route=isNode1 loadfactor=1
 #lbmethod=byrequests
 #ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
 </Proxy> Please help

Comment: You said you're using nginx? or httpd?